# How to execute more than one javafx application?

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, concurrency

Is there a way to execute more than one javafx app simultaneusly? I have a client app and a server one. I just want to execute one instance of server and many of the clients. In this way I can test concurrency of clients
. 
I thought I would use a thread for each client instance, but I really don't know.

The ultimate goal is simultaneously sending of many messages from clients.

Comment: use concurrency , checkout the documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: I know i have to use concurrency, your answer is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You should use threads, for every client one. Or you can make one JavaFX project for your server and one for your client. You can then run this client more times and you get more client.

But I think, that better way is to use threads for server and for clients.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.